# Store closing tags of an XML obj to an array using XMLDOM

Tags: json, xml, vbscript

Currently using `XMLDOM` object in VBScript to grab each node in an XML file. It returns the tags and the values just fine; however, I would like it to return the closing tags as well.

My end goal is to take the array and format to JSON. It has been difficult as of yet because there are situations where a Parent node may contain another Parent node in the XML making it difficult to know when to add `}` to close tags in JSON format.

Current Code:

```vb
Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM") 
xmlDoc.Async = "False" 
xmlDoc.Load(datatable("Filelocation", varSheet) & datatable("TC_Name", varSheet)) 
Set colNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes ("//") 
For Each objNode In colNodes 
    'MsgBox objNode.NodeName & " " & objNode.NodeValue
    value = objNode.NodeName
    MsgBox value
Next
```

Again, when I check `value` none of the closing tags are returned.  Is this possible using XMLDOM?  If not is there another way to successfully convert XML to JSON in VBScript?

Answer (score 0):

XML and JSON are both hierarchical datastructures. For a conversion between them you'd normally traverse the datastructure recursively and process the nodes like this:

1. Write the "open node" information (e.g. `{ "nodename":`)
2. Write text body or recurse into nested nodes.
3. Write the "close node" information (e.g. `}`).

A single loop will not suffice for arbitrary XML data.